# Юнити свойства и поля

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Я вынес передвижение игрока, атаку игрока и т.п в отдельные компоненты в каждом компоненте реализуется метод инициализации в который я передаю класс параметров игрока что бы каждый компонент брал то что ему нужно(скорость,урон и тд), но меня смущает то что любой компонент может спокойно поменять значение любой переменой(т.к поля в классе параметров игрока публичные) и что бы решить эту проблема я сделал что то на подобии этого

```
public float Speed
{
    get { return _speed; }
    private set { }
}
public float FieldView
{
    get { return _fieldView; }
    private set { }
}
public float AttackDelay
{
    get { return _attackDelay; }
    private set { }
}
public float ProjectileSize
{
    get { return _projectileSize; }
    private set { }
}

public int Damage
{
    get { return _damage; }
    private set { }
}

public int MaxHealth
{
    get { return _maxHealth; }
    private set { }
}

public int Health
{
    get { return _currentHealth; }
    private set { }
}

[SerializeField] private float _speed;
[SerializeField] private float _fieldView;
[SerializeField] private float _attackDelay;
[SerializeField] private float _projectileSize;
[SerializeField] private int _damage;
[SerializeField] private int _maxHealth;
[SerializeField] private int _currentHealth;
```

сделал приватные поля серилайзфилд(что бы настраивать из инспектора) и свойства которые читаются другим классом и не могут изменяться т.к сеттер приватный. Вопрос в том нормально ли это в юнити или это совсем бред делать по 2 переменные для одного и тоже только ради того что бы другие классы не могли менять переменные как им вздумается и что бы еще и было видно переменную в инспекторе?Заранее скажу что я вынес все важные переменные в отдельный класс т.к хочу сделать систему предметов которая меняет эти параметры и мне было бы удобно их видеть в 1 классе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что касается свойств, то да. Поскольку сериализатор `Unity` не работает с свойствами, методы чтения описываются публичными свойствами.

---

Если чтение отправляет значение поля, то зачем `set` вообще нужен?

```
public float MoveSpeed => _moveSpeed;
```

---

Как делаются статы можно посмотреть в серии уроков [Character Stats in Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SH25f3cXBVc&list=PLm7W8dbdflohqccuwJxjYRKuDUnk131XO) на <kbd>**YouTube**</kbd>.

Или скачать готовый [Character Stats](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/character-stats-106351) как раз по этой серии уроков в [image: Unity] <kbd>**Unity** *Assets Store*</kbd>, или какой-нибудь другой.

Comment: Тоесть все таки такой способ нормальный?Просто нигде не видел что бы так делали обычно ставят паблик и насрать

Comment: В видосах в интернетах, да.

Answer (score 0):

У юнити есть сериализатор автосвойств

```
[field:SerializeField] public int Number {get; set;}
```